# Proper way of using large array static member

Tags: c++, arrays, static, containers, stdarray

- I want a class to have ownership over a large array (at least 100000 elements).
- I have a class called `BaseProduct` (with members like `name` , `price` , `cost` , `print()`...)
- I have a class `BasicProductContainer` that will control the array of `BaseProduct`s.
- I tried having a shared pointer member to an array in my `BasicProductContainer`:

```
private:
    std::shared_ptr<std::array<BaseProduct, NUMBER_OF_PRODUCTS>> m_ptrArrProductContainer;
```

I want to avoid the array definition in the header file, so I did this in the class constructor in my `.cpp`:

```
static std::array<BaseProduct, NUMBER_OF_PRODUCTS> ProductContainer;

BasicProductContainer::BasicProductContainer() {
    m_ptrArrProductContainer = std::make_shared<std::array<BaseProduct, NUMBER_OF_PRODUCTS>>(ProductContainer);
}
```

This "works" but I'm wondering if there a better way? or a better looking one?  Is the pointer-to-array a good idea?

Comment: A `std::array` of 1M+ elements is rather odd. Are you sure you don't want to use `std::vector`?

Comment: Exactly what you are after is unclear to me, but it looks like every instance of `BasicProductContainer` will have its own copy of `ProductContainer`. DUnless the sharing comes in later, I don't see the purpose of the `shared_ptr`.

Comment: @Justin the array has a fixed size, why would I use a vector instead?

Comment: @user4581301 every instance of  `BasicProductContainer` should have its own container. I could consider a `unique_ptr`

Comment: `unique_ptr ` seems the more reasonable, lower overhead choice to me. What you get from the `std::vector` is the data is allocated in dynamic memory without any further effort on your part as well as being easily copied, moved, etc. The overhead will be minimal, maybe an extra pointer that you'll not even notice with a million+ element array.

Comment: If you use a `vector` instead, you don't even need the `unique_ptr` to place the actual data on the heap if that's why you use a pointer.

Comment: I'm convinced about the `unique_ptr` . But I will need a contiguous memory container, plus like the constant access time from the `std::arrays`  and I don't think I will have to copy/move the data => so by now, I think I'll keep the `std::array`

Comment: @Ivan `std::vector` uses a contiguous memory buffer, and constant-time random access

Answer (score 0):

If the array is not shared, I don't think it should be `shared_ptr`. Have you tried a `unique_ptr`?

There is also the `pimpl` idiom which is often used to avoid the definition of data in a header file:

```
// BasicProductContainer.h
class BasicProductContainerImpl; // forward declare pimpl
class BasicProductContainer {
private:
    std::unique_ptr<BasicProductContainerImpl> m_impl;
}

// BasicProductContainer.cpp
class BasicProductContainerImpl {
public:
  std::array<BaseProduct, NUMBER_OF_PRODUCTS>> arrProductContainer;
}

BasicProductContainer::BasicProductContainer()
  : m_impl(std::make_unique<BasicProductContainerImpl>())
{
    // m_impl->arrProductContainer to access the array
}
```

Note that the array is not `static`, but your comment on the main post that each `BasicProductContainer` should have its own container suggests that you don't want the `static`.

Comment: Maybe defining the size in the header confuses me, but won't this create a copy of the array each time I include it in a `.c`/`.cpp` file?

Comment: No. The array is only created when a `BasicProductContainer` is instantiated. Where you define the size of the array does not affect where/when the array is instantiated. If you have N `BasicProductContainer` instances, you will have N arrays.